# Can't load functions from dlls

Tags: c++, dll

I have made my very simple dll with two files:

- dllmain.cpp
- dll.hpp

dllmain.cpp:

```
#include "dll.h"
#include <windows.h>

messageimport::messageimport()
{
}

messageimport::~messageimport()
{
}

void messageimport::message()
{
MessageBox(0, "Hello World from DLL!\n","Hi",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL,DWORD fdwReason,LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
  switch(fdwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    {
        break;
    }
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    {
        break;
    }
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    {
        break;
    }
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    {
        break;
    }
}

/* Return TRUE on success, FALSE on failure */
return TRUE;
}
```

dll.hpp:

```
#ifndef _DLL_H_
#define _DLL_H_

#if BUILDING_DLL
#define DLLIMPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLIMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class DLLIMPORT messageimport
{
public:
    messageimport();
    virtual ~messageimport();

    void message();


};

#endif
```

and I use the dll from a file called dlltest.cpp

dlltest.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned int(WINAPI* message)(void);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

HMODULE dll = LoadLibrary("Call.dll");
if(dll != NULL){

    cout << "loaded dll \n";

    message func = (message)GetProcAddress(dll, "message");

    if(func != NULL)
    {
        cout << "found function";
    }else{  
        cout << "cant find function";
    }
}else{
    cout << "cant load the library";
}

return 0;
}
```

But when I run the dlltest.cpp It's output is like

```
Loaded dll
can't find function
```

Comment: so I need to change the line    'void message();' in dll.hpp to 'extern "C" void message() ' ???

Comment: sry how do I define BUILDING_DLL

Comment: In your preprocessor settings for the DLL.

Comment: I erased my comment because I expected you did that (correctly defined  BUILDING_DLL when building the DLL) and the real problem was due to you wanting to call a class member function using `GetProcAddress()`

Comment: Did you try calling `GetLastError`, to understand **why** it failed to load?

Comment: You are exporting ***class method***, not a function or static method. Generally, dll's are kinda old technology and not for exporting classes as is (see how COM works)

Comment: so how may I change my code

Comment: I removed functions from class deleting everything about class and then used extern "c" in front of functions ::  still nothing

Comment: Guys thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Here is good article why you [can't simple export  classes](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL)

Probably, you don't really want export class, so just pool out ***message*** from class  and export as just function. I'm sorry that I don't provide any code, no c++ atm.